# Intento llamar una función que tengo en otro controlador como lo hago?

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo esto:

```
class CocheController extends Controller
{
    public function generarBastidor() {
    }
}
```

// La quiero llamar desde:
   //como puedo hacerle?
    class VentaController extends Controller
    {
    }
>

Comment: Se puede, pero no deberías. Es considerorado una mala práctica y un "antipatrón". Si tienes un método en un controlador al que necesitas acceder en otro controlador, entonces esa es una señal que necesitas re-factorizar. Considera re-factorizar el método en un servicio, que luego puedes instanciar en múltiples controladores. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30365169/access-controller-method-from-another-controller-in-laravel-5

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. Estaba pensando en hacer un trait a ver si consigo hacerlo.

Comment: Claro, un trait es otra opción viable. En el link que te pasé hay varias opciones, las explicaciones están en inglés, pero mirando el código te puedes dar una idea. Cualquier cosa, sea cual sea el enfoque que elijas, puedes actualizar tu pregunta si te trabas en algo

Comment: Estoy haciendo el proyecto de fin de carrera y quiero usar ese mismo método en ambos controllers y lo que no quiero es tener lo mismo en dos, que además es grande intentaré lo trair, Gracias un saludo. Óscar.